# Things to consider when building a continuous integration server?

Tags: teamcity, build-server, continuous-integration

I'm new to continuous integration, but immediately realize its value, and I want to get one set up right away.  I have played with TeamCity and have it working in a VM great.

Now, I don't want to spend money on another system, so I was planning on just doing the VM again on a faster machine (i.e. my dev system).  There are a few questions that come to mind with this:

- Hard disk allocation - how big should it be?  Sure, 60GB seems like more than enough, but people also used to think that we'd *never* need more than 64KB of RAM
- Backups - is it even important to back up the integration server?  Sure, I guess it's nice so that one doesn't have to go through the entire configuration process again, but I would think that's about it.  I could snapshot my VM every time I do a configuration change, and then do a backup of applications only (ignore the buildAgent stuff).
- Migration - if I want to go away from a VM on my dev system, to a new server, which maybe even runs Windows Server 2003, is it easy enough?  Perhaps this is a particular point best suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your point:

1. Hard disk usage depends on how big the codebase and how often commits are made and how often the builds are made.
2. Backups should include configuration and build scripts only.
3. Probably migration could be the easiest when you migrate from *nix version of CI-server to win-version (e.g., when you migrate from linux version TeamCity to windows version of TeamCity). CI-systems do not implement any standard of some abstract continuous integration specification. And if you plan to migrate, for example, from TeamCity to Atlassian Bamboo, of from CruiseControl to Hudson is like to set up the CI-system from the scratch. The only generic thing for them is VSC-repository to take data from.

Comment: For #1, our codebase is tiny right now, but you never know.  I think in TC commits don't really matter because the code gets overwritten by the build agent each time.  However, the number of configurations  per project might make a difference.  If #2 and #3 are easy enough, then I guess it's not much of an issue.

For #3, I will stay on Windows for sure, so it's just a question of whether or not it's possible to "package" everything up and then move it over.

Comment: #3- I think it depends on CI-implementation. How easy it is possible to set it up and put configs which were previously backed up.